# DAX is not returning same value when using exact same statement, but with and without defining variables

Tags: powerbi, dax

Please refer to the syntax and table below. I'd like to use the variable, making it more efficient and readable of course, but it doesn't seem to work for me. It is the exact same statement, however I'm (not) defining the variable in the measure "testDAX" ("testDAX2").

I'm looking for the output value being 137, as given by testDAX. The 830 is simply the count of all rows in the table, without applying the filter of ProdCount = 1.

Just added the _tableD6 code. Then I copied the table in the DAX code exactly as is.

[image]

FYI: Curbal does the same thing in this video, starting at 3:00, but slightly less complex (without variables). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeV0ndga5kg&t=218s

Thanks in advance!

YK

[image: Visual showing testDAX2 is not working]

Code:

```
testDAX = 
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS (
            SUMMARIZE ( Orders, Orders[OrderID], "ProdCount", COUNT ( Orders[ProductID] ) )
        ),
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE ( Orders, Orders[OrderID], "ProdCount", COUNT ( Orders[ProductID] ) ),
            [ProdCount] = 1
        )
    )
```

and

```
testDAX2 = 
VAR _tableD6 =
    SUMMARIZE ( Orders, Orders[OrderID], "ProdCount", COUNT ( Orders[ProductID] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( _tableD6 ), FILTER ( _tableD6, [ProdCount] = 1 ) )
```

Comment: did you check the result from `_tableD6`

Comment: looks like  your filter context is not working as your declared VAR is not holding [Prodcount], check the '_tableD6' and if possible add the sample data to test

Comment: @Siva, thanks for your reply. Added screenshot of the code used to create the table. Also added the link to a video from Curbal where she does exactly the same but without defining variables.
Also, what do you mean with adding the sample data to test?

Comment: I can see redundancy in your code, why don't you apply filter in variable?

Comment: definitely. trying to improve step by step hehe. not an expert at all yet